How to stop page from refreshing when using useNavigation() from react-router-dom v6
I've seen many questions about this but none that work for me. Basically, I have a GameScreen component, where when the game starts, I want the URL path to change from "/roomcode/lobby" to "/roomcode/start".
const [roomCode, setRoomCode] = useState("");
const navigate = useNavigate();

useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("game_has_started", (info) => {
      navigate(`/${roomCode}/start`);
    });
  }, [socket]);

However, my page refreshes whenever the game starts, and thus the roomCode state resets to "", and the page goes to "//start", which breaks the app. How can I stop roomCode state from resetting when navigating?
edit: roomCode is 100% set to a non "" value before the "game_has_started" event is emmitted.

Can you [edit] to clarify what exactly you mean by "page refreshes" and "page goes to ://start""? I think there's more to this issue than the code you've shared. Can you include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?

Wait, is the issue here that roomCode has the initial state value of "" when the "game_has_started" event is emitted? Yes, we certainly do need a more complete code example to provide more help around when & where these events are emitted and handled here.

sorry, I should add info that roomCode has 100% been set to something else before this "game_has_started" event is emitted

Can you show us... in code?

Issue
At a minimum you have a stale Javascript Closure issue in the "game_has_started" event handler.

A closure is the combination of a function bundled together (enclosed)
with references to its surrounding state (the lexical environment). In
other words, a closure gives you access to an outer function's scope
from an inner function. In JavaScript, closures are created every time
a function is created, at function creation time.

The initial roomCode state value "" is closed over in the "game_has_started" event handler callback scope and won't ever change/update until the socket dependency updates, in which case it will only re-enclose only the current roomCode state value at that moment in the lifecycle.
Solution
Since the callback is pretty light you could likely get by with including the roomCode state in the useEffect hook's dependency array, and return a cleanup function to remove the previous handler.
Example:
const [roomCode, setRoomCode] = useState("");
const navigate = useNavigate();

useEffect(() => {
  const gameStartHandler =  () => {
    navigate(`/${roomCode}/start`);
  };

  socket.on("game_has_started", gameStartHandler);

  return () => {
    socket.off("game_has_started", gameStartHandler);
  };
}, [roomCode, socket]);

If the callback needed to do substantially more work or you just don't want to continually add/remove the handlers then an alternative is to cache the roomCode state into a React ref that can be mutated and referenced at any time in the component lifecycle.
Example:
const [roomCode, setRoomCode] = useState("");
const roomCodeRef = React.useRef(roomCode);
const navigate = useNavigate();

useEffect(() => {
  roomCodeRef.current = roomCode;
}, [roomCode]);

useEffect(() => {
  const gameStartHandler =  () => {
    navigate(`/${roomCodeRef.current}/start`);
  };

  socket.on("game_has_started", gameStartHandler);

  return () => {
    socket.off("game_has_started", gameStartHandler);
  };
}, [socket]);


useNavigate offers an optional replace parameter. By default, this parameter is set to false, which performs a "push" navigation.
This creates a new history entry. If the user clicks the back button, they'll navigate back to the previous page.
Setting replace to true will replace the current history entry instead of creating a new one.
This can be a way to prevent the page from appearing to reload  because the user stays within the same history entry.
Must go through with this https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate
Documentation of react router Dom.


The issue here is that you are using useState hook. Note that useState hooks are only available to a component. It's like a local variable. So, when you navigate to a new component, it's getting unmounted. And, that's why it goes from '/roomcode/lobby' to '//start'.
So, I suggest you to use localstorage to achieve your desired outcome which is persistence.
// put this code where you are generating the new room code
// replace newRoomCode with the new room code generated by your logic
localStorage.setItem('roomCode',newRoomCode)

// then change your useEffect hook as follows
useEffect(() => {
    const roomCode = localStorage.getItem('roomCode');
    socket.on("game_has_started", (info) => {
        navigate(`/${roomCode}/start`);
    });
}, [socket]);

Hopefully that should solve the issue!

hmm not really looking to use local storage, thanks though
